# how can I upload an image for the sendPhoto method of the API telegram bot

Tags: excel, vba, api, multipartform-data, telegram

I tried it but it did not work, where am I wrong?

The problem I think is in the transformation of the file for transmission through the POST request

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto][1](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto)

```
Sub SendPhoto()

Dim token As String: token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

'--- read file
    Dim adoStream
    Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    adoStream.Mode = 3          ' read write
    adoStream.Type = 1          ' adTypeBinary
    adoStream.Open
    adoStream.LoadFromFile ("C:\photo.png")
    adoStream.Position = 0
'--- post

Dim strPostData As String
Dim strResponse As String

strPostData = "chat_id=xxxxxxxx&photo=" & adoStream.Read()

 Dim HTTPReq As Object
    Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

HTTPReq.Open "POST", "https://api.telegram.org/bot" & token & "/sendPhoto", False
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"
HTTPReq.send (strPostData)

Debug.Print HTTPReq.responseText

Set HTTPReq = Nothing
Set adoStream = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the response you get from the current request?

Comment: Error 400, bad request :(